# How to turn off default notebook in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I want to change the default notebook to a blank one and I can't figure out how to turn off or change the default pre-populated notebook.

There is already a question for this here [Change RStudio Default R Notebook to blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333954/change-rstudio-default-r-notebook-to-blank)
, but I can't find the template called `r_markdown_notebook.Rmd` or any other similar named template. I'm using RStudio in Windows.

In the options menu, I've already unticked the option for "Execute setup chunk automatically in notebooks" and restarted etc but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any tips?

Comment: I know this is in the answer of the link you provided, but have you checked in your RStudio folder under resources/templates ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked there and also done various general searches from Explorer. There are other templates (github_document, html_vignette) but nothing for notebook.